# How to solve screen shifted to the left on wolfteam?

Tags: wolfteam

When I start Wolfteam (http://wolfteam.softnyx.net/) my screen is shifted to the left, that is, I cant see what is in the left of the screen since it starts showing the middle of the window. I have found some people on the internet with the same problem:

http://www.gamerzplanet.net/forums/wolfteam/240161-wolfteam.html

http://wolfteam.softnyx.net/Forum/FreeBoard_V.aspx?Seq=9623&cPage=1&searchCate=&searchValue=

I tried to change resolution in ingame options, but nothing happens, the resolution won't change: it changes the number I click OK but it won't actually change the resolution, only the resolution number configured.

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the onboard graphic card shipped with the PC was not compatible with the game. Even trying to use the most recent drivers it did not work. Installing an off board graphic card solved the problem.